# How do you tell a Qt app to depend on a Qt lib?

Tags: c++, qt, dependencies, dependency-management, qmake

I have a codebase where there are some shared libraries. For example LIB1 does some sort of processing that APP1 needs (depends on).

The qmake *.pro files are setup like the following. There is one root *.pro that is a `TEMPLATE=subdirs` that lists APP1 and LIB1 as it's subdirs.

LIB1.pro:

```
TARGET = LIB1
TEMPLATE = lib

QT += core
QT += xml

DESTDIR = path/to/libs/directory

SOURCES += \
    File1.cpp \
    FileN.cpp

HEADERS += \
    File1.h \
    FileN.h
```

APP1.pro:

```
#------ dependencies ------#
LIBS += -Lpath/to/libs/directory
# LIB1
INCLUDEPATH += path/to/libs/directory/LIB1lib
DEPENDPATH += path/to/libs/directory/LIB1lib
LIBS += -lLIB1

HEADERS       = \
    FileNplus1.h \
    FileM.h
SOURCES       = \
    FileNplus1.cpp \
    FileM.cpp
```

The problem is that when you compile the root *.pro file LIB1 will compile but APP1 fails to compile with the error `QDomElement: No such file or directory` because APP1.pro doesn't have `QT += xml`.

There is a hack that I use but I would like to overcome this hack. The hack involves adding the following line to APP1.pro:

```
# add this to APP1.pro... let's it compile again
QT += xml
```

**Is there anyway to setup your qmake *.pro files such that, `APP1.pro` depends on LIB1 without needing to modify `APP1.pro` to add the `QT += xml`?**

(The reason for this question is let's say you have other libraries that depend on other stuff... I would like to have Qt/Qmake take care of the dependencies like for example the `Qt += xml` dependency.)

Answer (score 2):

qmake allows you to create your [own configuration features](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.8-snapshot/qmake-advanced-usage.html). (last paragraph)

So you can create your own feature and move your lib1-linking code to it. You can add `QT+=xml` here. And in `app.pro` you'll just write `CONFIG += lib1`

Comment: Interesting! I'll check it out.